# Is there an Excel function to create a boolean vector?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, boolean, sumproduct

I'm just wondering if there is a way to create a boolean vector.

To give some context, I want to calculate a sumproduct function that is the following:
Count the number of rows that have an unique ID (which is in colum D) if the values in column F are equal to "A01" or "A02"

I have the beginning of a function, but I don't success to find the second part (which is XXX in my example):
=SUMPRODUCT(N(COUNTIF(Data!$D:$D;Data!$D:$D)=1)) * **XXX**)
I wanted to try something like that : =IF(Data!$F:$F={"A01","A02"},TRUE,FALSE) but it does not work.

Do you have some idea to help me please without creating an intermediary column?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `*((Data!$F:$F="A01")+(Data!$F:$F="A02"))`

Comment: or `*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Data!$F:$F,{"A01","A02"},0)))`

Comment: But one note, using full column references with SUMPRODUCT can be slow.  It is better to limit the column references to the most you expect the data size to be.  ie 10,000 rows is much better than 1million.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It really helps me (:
I'll take into account your advice.